# Wronskian - independent solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, wronskian

Question based on Example sheet 3, Problem 2 from here: https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/IA_M/differential_equations_eg.pdf

Could somebody tell me if there's a mistake in the initial conditions for $y_2$, because plugging those initial conditions back into the DE leads to $y_2^\prime(0)=0$ which along with $y_2(0)=0$ leads to the Wronskian being zero, and hence by Abel's theorem being zero for all $x$ and the solutions being dependent. Or have I misunderstood something?

Thanks.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.